# What is the difference between these os.popen calls?

Tags: python

I have two scripts:

The first works well:

```
import os
os.popen(‘grep abc filename’)
```

The second does not work:

```
import os
os.popen(‘grep abc’ + ’filename’)
```

But this does:

```
os.popen(‘grep abc filename’ + ‘>’ + ‘filename2’)
```

So, I can’t understand the difference. What is wrong about the second version?

Comment: There's no space between `abc` and `filename` in the 2nd command.

Comment: I assume you are running Python 2. You should be using [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) (or `subprocess32` if you are on a POSIX OS), `os.popen` is [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os.popen#os.popen).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the space after `abc` in the second version. It should be

```
import os
os.popen(‘grep abc ’ + ’filename’)
```

i.e. `abc˽'` vs `abc'`.